# Hide all elements of a class in a dom using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide all elements of classing in a dom using jquery.

In my case this works:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('hc-block hc-theme-nice-link hc-nowrap')[6].style.visibility='hidden'
```

but I want to hide all the elements (not just the 7-th one) and I would like to use Jquery

Tried this:

```
$(".hc-block hc-theme-nice-link hc-nowrap").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

but it does not work... Really dont understand why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jquery selector will need class to define with `.`, and you want to select element with all mentioned `class` so do not add space   between them. Try like below.

```
$(".hc-block.hc-theme-nice-link.hc-nowrap").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget to add `.` before all class and remove whitespace `" "` between them. Here down is example.

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
       $(".hc-block.hc-theme-nice-link.hc-nowrap").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="hc-block hc-theme-nice-link hc-nowrap">This is first paragraph.</span>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should address a class selector using `.`

It should be the list of classes with `.` without any space if all the classes are for the single node.

```
$(".hc-block.hc-theme-nice-link.hc-nowrap").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

if the dom structure is as below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".hc-block.hc-theme-nice-link.hc-nowrap").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hc-block hc-theme-nice-link hc-nowrap">
  content
</div>
```

**OR**

It should be the class elements seperated by   if the elements are one inside another

```
$(".hc-block .hc-theme-nice-link .hc-nowrap").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

if the dom structure is as below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".hc-block .hc-theme-nice-link .hc-nowrap").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hc-block">
  <div class="hc-theme-nice-link">
    <div class="hc-nowrap">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```